# Expanded TextField don't scroll when full

Tags: flutter

I'm building a screen where I have an expanded (`expanded` property set to true) `TextField` inside of a `Expanded` widget in a `Column`.

[image]

The `TextField` expand to take all the available space in the parent container, no problem with that. However, when I enter more text than the textfield can accommodate, it cause the parent `Container` to grow with it instead of scrolling inside the `TextField` causing an overflow.

Is there a way to have an expended `TextField` that still scroll when full ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using flex factor?

```
Expanded(
        flex: 2,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.amber,
          height: 100,
        ),
      ),
```

Watch this, maybe help
[Widget OF week](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rnZaagadyo)

Answer (score 0):

`Column` by itself is not scrollable. Meaning that if your column overflows vertically, whatever is underneath will not show up. So you should wrap your `Column` with `SingleChildScrollView` if you intend to make the column scrollable.